# Create new multidimensional array from flat array - directory paths - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Hope someone can point me in the right direction here...

I've got directory paths and partial file outputs form a unix grep. I have a flat array from these outputs. Now I'd like to do a bit of PHP magic to turn this flat array into a more hierarchical multidimensional array for more refined user output

Current array;

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(160) "/home/user/data/section1/dir1/20120107/filename.txt:random text after the colon"
  [1]=>
  string(160) "/home/user/data/section1/dir1/20120108/filename.txt: More random text after the colon"
  [2]=>
  string(160) "/home/user/data/section1/dir2/20120107/filename.txt: More random text after the colon"
  [3]=>
  string(160) "/home/user/data/section1/dir2/20120108/filename.txt: More random text after the colon"
  [4]=>
  string(160) "/home/user/data/section1/dir3/20120107/filename.txt: More random text after the colon"
  [5]=>
  string(160) "/home/user/data/section1/dir3/20120106/filename.txt: More random text after the colon"
  [6]=>
  string(160) "/home/user/data/section1/dir3/20120108/filename.txt: More random text after the colon"
}
```

What i would really like

```
array(1) {
    array(3) {
        ["dir"]=>
        string(4) "dir1"
        ["date"]=>
        string(8) "20120107"
        ["text"]=>
        array (2) {
          [0]=>
          string(160) "random text after the colon"
          [1]=>
          string(160) "More random text after the colon"
          }
    }
    array(3) {
        ["dir"]=>
        string(4) "dir1"
        ["date"]=>
        string(8) "20120108"
        ["text"]=>
        array (2) {
          [0]=>
          string(160) "More random text after the colon"
          [1]=>
          string(160) "More random text after the colon"
          }
    }
    array(3) {
        ["dir"]=>
        string(4) "dir2"
        ["date"]=>
        string(8) "20120107"
        ["text"]=>
        array (2) {
          [0]=>
          string(160) "More random text after the colon"
          [1]=>
          string(160) "More random text after the colon"
          }
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of foreach's, SPL iterator methods, but i'm just not coming out trumps. Looking for any guidance.

Thanks all

Comment: Can you post what you have tried.

Comment: It's not clear why you have two "random" strings for each entry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the input and scripts. I have actually learned quite a bit about massaging data into multidimensional arrays from these scripts. Unfortunately, none of them worked out exactly as i wanted. One thing i've learned researching this issue, is, 'is there another way to present the data?' and in this case i found it. A shell script, to search all files, output the filename, and then the relevant text.

```
find /home/user/data/section1 -name 'filename.txt' | xargs grep -il texttxet | 
   while read file 
       do
          echo "$file"
          grep -i  -A 4 texttxet "$file" 
       done

File:/home/user/data/section1/dir1/20120107/filename.txt
line1
line2
line3

File:/home/user/data/section1/dir1/20120108/filename.txt
line1
line2

File:/home/user/data/section1/dir2/20120108/filename.txt
line1
line2
```

I can easily get this info in an array from this point. Thanks all again

Answer (score 2):

This code (using a `for` loop):

```
<?php
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir1/20120107/filename.txt:random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir1/20120108/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir2/20120107/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir2/20120108/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir3/20120107/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir3/20120106/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir3/20120108/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";

for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $data[$i] = str_replace('/home/user/data/section1/','',$data[$i]);
    $tmp = explode('/', $data[$i]);

    $newData[$i] = array(
        'dir' => $tmp[0],
        'date' => $tmp[1]
    );

    $tmp = explode(':', $tmp[2]);

    $newData[$i]['fileName'] = $tmp[0];
    $newData[$i]['text'] = $tmp[1];
}

print_r($newData);
?>
```

Or this code (using a `foreach` loop):

```
<?php
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir1/20120107/filename.txt:random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir1/20120108/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir2/20120107/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir2/20120108/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir3/20120107/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir3/20120106/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";
$data[] = "/home/user/data/section1/dir3/20120108/filename.txt: More random text after the colon";

foreach($data as $d) {
    $tmp = explode('/', str_replace('/home/user/data/section1/','',$d));
    $tmp2 = explode(':', $tmp[2]);

    $newData[] = array(
        'dir' => $tmp[0],
        'date' => $tmp[1],
        'filename' => $tmp2[0],
        'text' => $tmp2[1]
    );
}

print_r($newData);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dir] => dir1
            [date] => 20120107
            [fileName] => filename.txt
            [text] => random text after the colon
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dir] => dir1
            [date] => 20120108
            [fileName] => filename.txt
            [text] =>  More random text after the colon
        )

============ more data here ============

    [6] => Array
        (
            [dir] => dir3
            [date] => 20120108
            [fileName] => filename.txt
            [text] =>  More random text after the colon
        )

)
```

Comment: Good, but why the `for` loop instead of a `foreach`?

Comment: No reason, I've added a `foreach` example now too :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a foreach over the first array and preg_match() the elements for the informations you want to extract from each string.

```
foreach( $firstArray => $strElement )
{
   $newArray[] = array();

   if( preg_match( "~(?<=section1/)[.-\w]*~i", $strElement, $astrMatches) >= 1 )
     $newArray['dir'] = $astrMatches[0];
   ...etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) each string of path with "/".You will get an array after that.Then push required element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function magic($array_of_strings)
{
    define('REGEX','_^/home/user/data/section1/(dir\d+)/(\d+)/filename.txt:(.*)$_');
    $ret_array = array();

    foreach($array_of_strings as $string) {
        if (preg_match(REGEX, $string, $matches)) {
            $ret_array []= array(
              'dir'=>$matches[1],
              'date'=>$matches[2],
              'text'=>$matches[3],
            );
        }
    }
    return $ret_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this will do the job, you can change the directory structure as much as you like as long as the the last two directories keep the same order `/dir/date`.

You can add as many strings as you like to the `text` section of the array by seperating them with multiple colons after the URL. e.g. `/blah/dir/date/filename.txt : string 1 : string 2`.

Your original array must be called `$array`.

Enjoy:

```
foreach ($array as $string) {
   $temp = array();
   $temp["strings"] = explode(':', $string); //Convert the string into an array using `:` as a seperator
   $temp["path"] = explode('/', $temp["strings"][0]); //Convert the url into an array using `/` as a seperator (each directory is it's own entry)
   $path_count = count($temp["path"]); //Count number of directories in the url
   $output = array(
      "dir" => $temp["path"][$path_count - 3],
      "date" => $temp["path"][$path_count - 2],
      "text" => array()
   );
   foreach ($temp["strings"] as $index => $value) { //Loop through and add any additional text to array
      if ($index) {
         array_push($output["text"], trim($value));
      }      
   }
   print_r($output);
}
```